# Ubuntu 16.04: Why there is no unity in Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, libreoffice, syslog

I have opened 2 applications:

1. System Log

   [image: System Log]
2. LibreOffice Writer

   [image: LibreOffice Writer]

After observing open dialog from both these application, I found that both of these has different UI.

It seems like Ubuntu 16.04 has some gnome UI and some unity specific.
Why their is not unity in this Unity?

I have couple of other examples that shows this different.

Another example which shows gnome UI (context menu) in Ubuntu 16.04:

[image]

Whereas in Ubuntu 14.04 it has unity specific UI.

Comment: I'd blame internal programming :P I think system log has been made back in the gnome era (you will be missed ) and not been updated to unity UI

Comment: I will add other example, which has unity UI in Ubuntu 14.04 and gnome UI in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: You do not have these 'gnome bugs' in 14.04?

Comment: Yes I don't have at least for third pic I pasted in question.

Comment: Then I would say its a bug in 16.04.. hrm....

Comment: Because of this, most of the users doesn't like these type of UI bugs and then they move to other distros or UIs instead of Unity.

Comment: Hey now lets not forget 16.04 is quite new :) 
and another question, did you upgrade from 14.04 or just an entire new installation?

Comment: That's true and its entirely new installation.

Comment: Hrm.. if it was an upgrade I could understand the bugs, so this.. is odd

Answer (score 0):

The file choose dialog depends on the GUI toolkit developers used in creating their software. Gtk file chooser will look  different from Qt file chooser.  Below is the example of either, both running from scripts

[image]

It also bears no relation to Gnome, because again - file chooser depends on program's toolkit, not desktop environment.

In case of Gtk toolkit, the difference also may depend on the Gtk version used. Compare [Gtk 3.0](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html)  and [Gtk 2.0](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) file chooser dialogs. Difference is noticeable